# WPF - Change the place of a control in a grid in code-behind

Tags: wpf-controls

Is it possible to change where a control is placed in a grid from code-behind?

For example, if I have a Button in Grid.Row="1", can I change that to Grid.Row="0" from code-behind?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. Just go:

```
Grid.SetRow(button,0);
```

where button is the element to change.