# How can I dynamically add TextBox to Grid?

Tags: c#, xaml

I am trying to programmically add `TextBox` in my Grid.

Here is my code:

```
private async void NavigationHelper_LoadState(object sender, LoadStateEventArgs e)
        {
            var input= await OneListDataSource.GetItemAsync((string)e.NavigationParameter);
 foreach (string item in input.getItems()) {
            TextBox textBox = new TextBox();
                textBox.Text = item;
                grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());
                grid.Children.Add(textBox);
            }
}
```

And in my xaml:

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1" x:Name="ContentRoot" Margin="19,9.5,19,0">

        </Grid>
```

But when I run it in simulator, I only see 1 row and all the item seems overlapping each other.
I tried remove `Grid.Row` in my xaml file, but I don't see it make any difference.

Updated:

Thanks for the answers, I almost get this to work. Now my question is 
Why I need to add a new RowDefintion() everything I add a new children(), can I do it without RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition()) for each row?

```
foreach (string item in input.getItems()) {
            TextBox textBox = new TextBox();
                textBox.Text = item;
                grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());  // why I need to do this everytime I add a new TextBox?
                Grid.SetRow(textBox, i++);
                Grid.SetColumn(textBox, 0);
                grid.Children.Add(textBox);
            }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [WPF - Change the place of a control in a grid in code-behind](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3785572/wpf-change-the-place-of-a-control-in-a-grid-in-code-behind)

Comment: ... or also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7127125/how-to-add-wpf-control-to-particular-grid-row-and-cell-during-runtime).

Comment: if you just want to show a list of textboxes, how about using a stackpanel instead?

Comment: or even better, an items control

Comment: I look into items control. How can I programically add a TextBox to an itemsControl?

Comment: take a look at http://www.wpftutorial.net/Layout.html and read up about the different containers available in WPF. In your example, each textbox also needs to have a Grid.Row="x" decoration or else they will all be assigned to Grid.Row="0" by default. x is the 0-based row number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A RowDefinition is needed because that is how the Grid control handles its Children. If two controls inside the Grid are in the same row and column they will draw on top of each other based on the order they are added to the Grid. A Grid control does not respect the boundaries of controls that it contains, it only cares about which controls are in each row and column. A [WrapPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.wrappanel(v=vs.110).aspx) however, does not require rows and columns. It will position controls it contains in a "grid like" fashion until it reaches the width or height bounds of itself based on the value of the Orientation property.